# I want to fetch images which I've stored locally from my backend. The object Contains the address of images locally. I want that object to be fetched

Tags: node.js, reactjs, connection, fetch, backend

My request at frontEnd

```
React.useEffect(() => {
if(!props.name)
return;
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/${props.name}`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("Respponse from Server" ,data);
    setStoryData(data);
  });
}, [props.name]);
```

The data I want to be returned here is:

```
{
  name: "Ronnie",
  img1: __dirname + '/contactData/car1.jpg',
  img2: __dirname + '/contactData/car2.jpg',
  img3: __dirname + '/contactData/car3.jpg',
}
```

Address are of images stored locally. I've Checked manually they are working

[image: This is the error I am getting when I try to fetch the request]

Comment: I think the response you get is not a valid json. check the ${props.name} api.

Comment: Yes, I'm bit new to these things, how could I make a valid json

Comment: Post the api code. Its hard to see whats wrong without having the full picture.

Comment: Remove the last "," and it should be fine. Have a look at https://www.json.org/json-en.html.